# In Visual Studio 2019, It show "loading.... The design surface is loading" when I create the table in data connections, not show the table

Tags: database, visual-studio-2019, loading, design-surface

I create the database in Visual Studio 2019 for first. Firstly, I went to Sever Explorer and did add connection. I enter to the that data and Right Click to the Table and click on Add New Table. After that, it shows "loading.... The design surface is loading" for like a long time and it didn't show up nothing on visual studio. that is a image of loading [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfLIm.png) Please tell me a solution for that problems. I just google it but i can't find out.

Please tell me a solution for that problems. I just google it but i can't find out. My laptop Ram is still around 3GB available when i use C# in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my working laptop...
Usually switching out into code tab and back solves the issue
If this does not help I drag the separator that separates the T-SQL and design panel (down or up it does not matter).
That usually solves the issue, but I think this is a bug in the VS because many guys in the office face the same issue.
Also, a colleague of mine says that it helps him to right-click => open with, and use different editor